# How do I programatically remove Menus?

Tags: menus, navigation

I know that each menu item is simply post present in `nav_menu_item` post type. It has has ID and can be removed with `wp_delete_post()` but posts deleted this way don't remove menus present under [Appearance > Menus]. Only menu items are removed.

For instance I have "My Menu" under [Appearance > Menus] that has the following items: page-1, page-2, category-3. I can remove menu items with `wp_delete_post()` but "My Menu" (group for those items) remains intact.

How can I programatically remove all defined Menus (and menu items)?

Comment: It’s quite easy to interpret this question in many different ways. Any chance of posting a screenshot of what you’re trying to accomplish?

Comment: I added example. Basically, under [Appearance > Menus] I can create menu that has items. Items can be removed with `wp_delete_post()` but this doesn't remove "Menu Group" that they were in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check wp_delete_nav_menu() function. If you want to get all nav menus you can check wp_terms table or

```
$menu_list = get_terms('nav_menu');
```

to get a list of it.